# If $\pi$ and $\pi^*$ are dual projection operators in $E, E^*$, show that $Im ( \pi^*) = (ker\pi)^\perp$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

> Let $E,E^*$ be dual spaces($E^*$ doesn't have to be $L(E)$).Suppose $\pi: E \to E$ and $\pi^*: E^* \to E^*$ are dual
>   mappings.Assume that $\pi$ is a projection operator in E. Prove that
>   $\pi^*$ is a projection operator in $E^*$ and that
>   $$Im ( \pi^*) = (ker\pi)^\perp$$ 
>   and  $$Im(\pi) = (ker \pi^*)^\perp$$

I have shown that $\pi^*$ is also a projection operator, but I have now idea how to show the following relations.

I would appreciate any help.

Note: The sign $A^\perp$ means the orthogonal space of A, i.e
$$(ker\pi)^\perp = \{ x^* \in E^* | <x^*, x> = 0 \quad \forall x \in ker\pi  \}$$

Note: We are not assuming neither $E$ nor $E^*$ is finite.

Comment: what is the definition of dual mapping ?

Comment: @TsemoAristide See the page 67, section 2.24 in the book of _Linear Algebra_ by Werner Greub

Comment: @TsemoAristide the link to the book: http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4…

Comment: Does the superscript $\perp$ designate “annihilator?” If so, then the latter is a property of dual mappings in general (though it would make a bit more sense to me to write $\ker\pi^*=\operatorname{im}(\pi)^\perp$ in that case).

Comment: @amd $\perp$ means the orhogonal.

Comment: This seems nonsensical to me. How can the image of $\pi^*$ be orthogonal to any subset of $E$ when it’s a subspace of an entirely different vector space?

Comment: @amd $Im \pi^* \subseteq E^*$ and $(\ker \pi)^\perp \subseteq E^*$.Note that $(ker\pi)^\perp = \{ x^* \in E^* | <x^*, x> = 0 \quad \forall x \in ker\pi  \}$, where $<,>$ is the bilinear function between $E,E^*$

Comment: You use a very different meaning of “orthogonal” than I do. To me it is a type error to call a function $\phi:E\to\mathbf K$, which is what an element of $E^*$ is, orthogonal to an element of $E$. They are completely different types of objects and live in different spaces.

Comment: @amd I'm not calling a function orthogonal to an element of $E$, $A^\perp$ represents the set of elements whose "scalar product" is zero with the all elements in $A$.Since I'm talking about the scalar products, the orthogonal elements must be in the dual space of $A$.See the book of _Linear Algebra_ by Werner Greub for more detailed information.

Comment: Sounds like Greub is playing a bit fast and loose with isomorphisms. Strictly speaking, the dual space of $E$ consists of linear functionals $\phi: E\to\mathbb K$. There’s a natural isomorphism between this space and $E$, and after making this identification it makes sense to speak of orthogonality.

Comment: @amd the set of linear functions of $E$ is just one of the dual spaces of $E$, the concept of dual space is much more general than the set of linear functions.I mean most of the intro linear algebra books are giving the dual space as $L(E)$, the set of linear function of $E$, the definition of dual space is not $L(E)$.

Comment: the two equations hold for general linear bounded operator.

Comment: @C.Ding Yes, I know, but I need to prove for an arbitrary dual space $E^*$ and projection operators defined in the question.

Comment: Since you know the general case holds and the proof is just several lines, why you have to proove the special case?

Comment: @C.Ding Which general case are you talking about ?

Comment: Oh, is $E$ just a vector space?

Comment: @C.Ding Yes, what else did you think ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62270/discussion-between-c-ding-and-leth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{Im}}$ $\newcommand{\ang}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}$
First, for a general linear operator $u:E\to E$,

> $$(\im u)^\perp=\ker u^*;(\im u^*)^\perp=\ker u.$$

In fact,
$$\begin{align*}
(\im u)^\perp &=\{x^*\in E^*|\ang{x^*,ux} = 0,\forall x\in E\}\\
&=\{x^*\in E^*|\ang{u^*x^*,x}=0,\forall x\in E\}\\
&=\{x^*\in E^*|u^*x^*=0\}=\ker u^*.
\end{align*}
$$

Second, for a projection $\pi$,

> $$(\im\pi)^{\perp\perp}=\im \pi.$$

Indeed, $E=\pi E\oplus (1-\pi)E,$

so $$\forall x\in (\pi E)^{\perp\perp},\quad x=y+z,$$ where $y\in \pi E$ and $z\in (1-\pi) E,$ $$0=(1-\pi)x=(1-\pi)y+(1-\pi)z=0+z=z$$
since  $1-\pi\in (\pi E)^\perp$.
Thus $x=y\in \pi E$, another direction is just by definition.

Therefore, $\im \pi=(\im\pi)^{\perp\perp}=(\ker u^*)^\perp.$
And the other is similary.

Comment: If $E$ is not finite, then $(\im u)^\perp=\ker u^*;(\im u^*)^\perp=\ker u$ doesn't hold.

Comment: By the way, I have no idea what you mean by $(1-\pi)E$ in $E=\pi E\oplus (1-\pi)E$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{Im}}$ $(1-\pi) E$ means $\im(1-\pi)$.

Comment: So, $1$ is the identity function then ?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: I have still questions, so it is better we again continue our discussion on the chat, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62270/discussion-between-c-ding-and-leth

Comment: $\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{Im}}$ $\newcommand{\ang}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}$ $$\begin{align*}
(\im u^*)^\perp &=\{x\in E|\ang{u^*x^*,x} = 0,\forall x^*\in E^*\}\\
&=\{x\in E|\ang{x^*,ux}=0,\forall x^*\in E^*\}\\
&=\{x\in E|ux=0\}=\ker u.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $y^* \in Im ( \pi^*)$. Then $y^*=\pi^*(x^*)$ for some $x^* \in E^*$. Then we have for $x \in ker \pi$:

$y^*(x)=x^*( \pi(x))=0$, hence $y^* \in (ker\pi)^\perp$, therefore

$Im ( \pi^*) \subseteq (ker\pi)^\perp$.

The rest is your turn !

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but rest is still not clearer at all.